# I'd like footnotes at bottom of page rather than end of document

Tags: footnotes

new user here.

I'm using overleaf and not sure if its the template I choice or a coding issue, but when I try to get a footnote:

```
\footnotetext[1]{text}
```

It puts the footnote at the end of the whole document in a notes section rather than at the bottom of the page where I would like it.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! .Look for `\usepackage{endnotes}` inside the `.cls` file (if any) or inside possible `.sty` files.

Comment: Which class are you using?

Comment: @DaiBowen documentclass{ndjflart}

Comment: @koleygr Thanks for the reply! what do you mean "inside the .cls file . . . " ? And is \usepackage{endnotes} code that I should type in?

Comment: There is a `ndjflart.cls` file probably in your "working directory" (in the files used). Click project on your up and left (next to Overleaf logo) and you will find it there.

Comment: If the document class is provided/required by a journal, don't mess with it.  If not, why use it?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, try to find if somewhere in your main (`.tex`) file is a command `\usepackage{endnotes}` (If it is there it will be before `\begin{document}` command). If not there, may be in your `.cls` file (anywhere), and if not there too possibly (anywhere) in included `.sty` files.

The behavior you are describing is not a default `LaTeX` behavior but possibly caused from the above specific package. But this is not absolute... There is a (smaller) possibility to find in your code (one of the the above files) a command like

`\def\footnote{...}`

or

`\renewcommand\footnote[2][]{...}`

Please answer what of these happened, to help you overcome the problem. Also, if you are preparing a specific document for specific needs that need specific (:P) template, then you have to think or ask about changing that... (In case of preparing a publication). If not, it is better to start with simple "templates" like a simple `book` or an `article` `documentclass`.

**Edit:**

Found these lines in your documentclass:

```
\let\footnote\endnote % todo: is it necessary? 
                      % todo: if so - complete definition, footnotemark, etc. 
\let\footnotetext\endnote
```

It doesn't give the freedom to go back to original footnote, but we can hack it like this:

```
\let\oldfootnote\footnote %STEP1: ADD THIS LINE AT THE BEGINNING OF YOUR FILE
\documentclass{ndjflart}
\let\footnote\oldfootnote  %STEP2: ADD THIS LINE JUST AFTER \documentclass command
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\footnote\oldfootnote
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{test}
\lipsum\footnote{Here}
\end{document}
```

PS: As I said above, do it only if you really have to and after discussion with the "publisher" (if any)

Comment: I found this: }
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
  \@setfontsize\small{8}{10}%
}                                                      in the .cls. Also, (sidenote) how can I hit enter (on macbook) in this comment box and not send the message? haha

Comment: Does my edit fix your problem? See STEP1 and STEP2 of the last code

Comment: Which file do I put this in? I added it to the .tex file but it did not do anything

Comment: Only one file contains `\documentclass` command. It is your main file. Also, I tried the above code to see if works before posting. You need to do both "STEPS"